# How to make Lavacharts Responsive

Tags: php, laravel, charts, responsiveness

I am using `Lavacharts` in my `Laravel` web application. Rendering the `chart` in a `view` in something like this:

```
<?php
    echo Lava::render('DonutChart', 'malik', 'malik', array('width' => 400, 'height' => 400));
?>
```

The `height` and the `width` element here is absolute. 
I went through this [Link](https://github.com/kevinkhill/Lavacharts/issues/9#ref-issue-47694510) which describes the use of `Lava::get('chartName')` but I don't know how and where in my code to use it.

How may I use it? any help?

Comment: I thought that LavaChart by default is already reponsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, One way to do this is apply your own styling upon this. `Lavacharts` takes the second argument in the `render` method and assigns it as an `id` to the `div`. So using the `id` I styled it like this:

```
#malik{
      height: 100% !important;
      width: 100% !important;
}
```

And it worked!